# Unit test dao layer without in memory database

Tags: junit4

Is there a way to Unit test dao layer without in memory database like h2?Most of the examples out there use in memory databases for dao calls.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you would like to test there.

If you would like to verify the result of query execution, you'll need some data, and that would need a physical or in-memory database. You can use JDBC connections for plain queries or Hibernate to inject an EntityManager into your DAO layer, and then test it. I think one advantage of in-memory database is that we define exactly what data will be used, instead of depending on a physical database data, that might change with time.

On another perspective, you might be wanting to check the construction of the queries, when there are some logic involved. For this, you won't need any data, Mockito method interception and ArgumentCaptor could be helpful to obtain the constructed (native or HQL) query, and then you could compare the result with the expected query. I've seen such a solution using xml properties, that also serve as a kind of documentation and regression test against accidental changes on sensible queries.